# How to use Map to bound a values on parameters of java method from URI in Rest API

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

```
@GET
@Path("/getResults/{names}/view")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getResults(@QueryParam("names") Map<String, String> names) {
    System.out.println(names);
    return "someValue";
}
```

Explanation:  We are trying to bind a value to java.util.map parameter from URI, but not getting it.

Comment: It could be mapped with string. How come names could be a key-value

Comment: You can use JsonObject or JsonString with this, at server which can be converted back to retrieve array of names.

Comment: Inject [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) and use `uriInfo.getQueryParameters()`. It returns a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>`

Answer (score 0):

Accept string as Query params.
Then convert the string to map using gson.

```
@GET
@Path("/getResults/{names}/view")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getResults(@QueryParam("names") String names) {

    Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(names, Map.class)        
    return "someValue";
}
```